# How to insert a row and a column in a recursive table

Tags: python, python-2.7, export-to-csv

I'm posting this question because I've tried over and over without results.
I have written a table that prints in the shell of Python 2.7 and exports to CSV the inputs given in a nested `for` loop. I'm facing some troubles because I need to display both on shell and CSV export the initial values used by the loop. In practice, I need to display a first row that contains all the possible values that `t` assumes (i.e. 8) and add a first column that contains the corresponding values that `s` assumes (i.e. 15). Since Python commands `print` and `wr.writerow` manage tables with rows, I don't know how to solve the issue. Here's the code:

```
import csv
with open('chill.csv', 'wb') as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    data = ([str(13.127 + 0.6215 * t - 11.362 * s ** 0.16 + 0.396 * t * s ** 0.16)
                 for t in range(-25, 15, 5)]
                     for s in range(0, 75, 5))
    for row in data:
        print('\t'.join(row))
        wr.writerow(row)
```

I hope that anybody can help!

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Your code seems to work fine. Are you saying that you need a row with header information and a leading column with header information? Please update the question with a sample of how you want it to appear.

Comment: Do you need to create `data` at once, or can you simple create the as you go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution generating the file as you progress, instead of trying to generate a `data` variable with all lists.

```
import csv

# For readability, extract the cell calculation
def calc_cell(t, s)
    return 13.127 + 0.6215 * t - 11.362 * s ** 0.16 + 0.396 * t * s ** 0.16

with open('chill.csv', 'wb') as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)

    def add_row(row):
        "Add a new row to both console and file"
        row = map(str, row)  # Coerce values to str, for join
        print('\t'.join(row))
        wr.writerow(row)

    # Add the "header row"
    add_row([' '] + range(-25, 15, 5))

    # Create the table, one row at a time
    for s in range(0, 75, 5):
        add_row([s] + [calc_cell(t,s) for t in range(-25, 15, 5)])
```